# Autofocus a dxtextbox at page load And Showing a dxTooltip as validation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, devextreme

I am facing some issue related to auto-focus for a particular text box I tried several things but none of them are working.
And also I want to show a dxtooltip for a checkbox containing message if validation fails,Since the default dxCheckBox is not showing any validation
message,and i don't want to show a summery for validation.

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'home', title: 'Home' } " >
<div class="home-view dx-content-background"  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >
    <div class="dx-field">
        <div class="dx-field-label">Password:</div>
        <div class="dx-field-value"><div id="password"></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dx-field">
        <div class="dx-field-label">Confirm Password:</div>
        <div class="dx-field-value"><div id="repassword"></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dx-field">
        <div class="account-header" id="cb_accept"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="btn-finish" data-bind="dxButton: {text: 'Finish', onClick: validateAndSubmit}"></div>


</div>
```

```
sampleproject.home = function (params, viewInfo) {

var openTabsAsRoot = viewInfo.layoutController.name === "split",
    isReady = $.Deferred();


function validateAndSubmit(params) {
    var result = params.validationGroup.validate();
    if (result.isValid) {
        handlefinish();
    }
}

function handleViewShown() {
    loadOptionData();
}

var comparisonTarget = function () {
    var txtPassword = $("#password").dxTextBox('instance');
    if (txtPassword.option('value')) {
        return txtPassword.option('value');
    }
}

function loadOptionData() {


    //$('#password').focus();
    //$("#password:text:visible:first").focus();


    //window.onload = function () {
    //    $("#password").focus();
    //};
    //$('#password :input').focus();

    //window.onload = function () {
    //    document.getElementById("password").focus();
    //};        

    $("#password").focus();
    $("#password").dxTextBox({
        placeholder: 'Required',
    }).dxValidator({
        validationRules: [{
            type: "required",
        }]
    });
    $("#repassword").dxTextBox({  
        placeholder: 'Required',  
    }).dxValidator({
        validationRules: [{ type: 'compare', comparisonTarget: comparisonTarget }]            
    });
    $("#cb_accept").dxCheckBox({
        value: false,
        text: "Terms and condition "
    }).dxValidator({
        validationRules: [{
            type: "compare",
            comparisonTarget: function () { return true; },
            message: "Please Accept the Terms and Conditions"
        }]
    });
}

function handlefinish() {
    alert('Success');
}


return {
    isReady: isReady.promise(),
    viewShown: handleViewShown,
    handlefinish: handlefinish,
    validateAndSubmit: validateAndSubmit
}
```

};

please help me to sort this out

Answer (score 0):

To focus a dxTextBox you can use the [focus](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTextBox/Methods/?version=15_2#focus) method of the dxTextBox instance:

```
$("#textbox").dxTextBox({/* some options */}).dxTextBox("instance").focus();
```

So, you can update the `loadOptionData` function like this:

```
function loadOptionData() {
    //...
    $("#password").dxTextBox({
        placeholder: 'Required',
    }).dxValidator({
            validationRules: [{
            type: "required",
        }]
    });

    $("#password").dxTextBox("instance").focus();

    //...
}
```

As for validation of a dxCheckBox, you can easily implement it using the following code:

```
$("#check").dxCheckBox({
    value: false,
    text: "I agree to the Terms and Conditions",
    validationMessageMode: "always"
}).dxValidator({
    validationRules: [{
        type: "compare",
        comparisonTarget: function() {
            return true;
        },
        message: "You must agree to the Terms and Conditions"
    }]
});
```

Here I use the compare validator. Also, I use `validationMessageMode: "always"` to show a validation tooltip always.

I've created the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gvx8q932/, as well.

Comment: I really appreciate your help,"validationMessageMode: "always"" is working fine but auto-focus is not at all working in my code .Can you please suggest me some other way to implement that.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle that demonstrates your issue with auto-focus?

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to implement it in fiddler. I need auto-focus in page load.You can refer the code what I have given

Comment: I've updated my answer and added updated code from your example.